# Как склоняется "Альфа Центавра"?

Tags: грамматика, склонение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как склоняется "Альфа Центавра"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так обозначается двойная звезда в созвездии Центавра, поэтому склоняется только первое слово, а для второго сохраняется родительный падеж со значением "принадлежности Центавру".

> Альфа Центавра
>
> Альфы Центавра
>
> Альфе Центавра
>
> Альфу Центавра
>
> Альфой Центавра
>
> об Альфе Центавра